# VB.NET IsNothing() Not Working as Expected?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a query like so:

```
 Dim clcexists = (From p In dbContext.Signatures _
                          Where p.StudentID = people_id _
                         And p.ContractType = "clc" _
                          Order By p.ID Descending _
                           Select p)
```

Later I check whether any rows exist in clcexists using IsNothing like so:

```
   If IsNothing(clcexists) Then ' If no CLC is on file.
            clcfirst = Date.Now.Subtract(year)
            clcdate = clcfirst
        Else ' If CLC is on file.
            clcfirst = clcexists.FirstOrDefault()
            clcdate = clcfirst.SignatureDate
        End If
```

But IsNothing() is not functioning like I expect. There is no row in the results table, but it is still acting as if there is and going to the Else clause. Help?

Comment: Try appending `.ToList()` and then check count of `clcexists`

Comment: @PankajGarg: No need to append `.ToList()` just to check if there are rows. Use `.Any()` as mentioned in Tim Schmelter's answer.

Comment: @PankajGarg: Woul be a little bit ineffective to execute the whole query just to look if there's one element and then take the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) instead:

```
If Not clcexists.Any() Then ' no CLC is on file.
    clcfirst = Date.Now.Subtract(year)
    clcdate = clcfirst
Else ' If CLC is on file.
    clcfirst = clcexists.FirstOrDefault()
    clcdate = clcfirst.SignatureDate
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

`IsNothing` checks if a reference has an object instance assigned to it (I.e. It is not `null`). In your case the object is not `null`, as it points to an instance with no rows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.71).aspx

You should use `Rows.Count`, `Rows.Any()` or the `HasRows` property to check if rows exist on your instance.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem as well as giving the correct code!

Comment: Thanks MarkJ. I think it is important that the OP understands _why_ as well as _how_ to fix the problem. The answer is worth nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use the HasRows property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows.aspx